# Asp.Net membership errors 

Tags: asp.net-membership

I have 2 databases that a mirrors of eachother schmatically.  The data is the only thing that is different.  When I try to log into the second database I keep getting this error -

> The
>   System.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider
>   requires a database schema compatible
>   with schma version '1' However the
>   current database schema is not
>   compativle with this version.  You may
>   need to wither install a compatible
>   schema with aspnet_regsql.exe or
>   upgrade the provider to a newer
>   version

When I check the dbo.aspnet_SchemaVersions I see the following:

common  1   True
health monitoring   1   True
membership  1   True
personalization 1   True
profile 1   True
role manager    1   True

What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that both applications are using the same version of ASP.NET and the Membership provider.

Comment: How do I do that, they are both on the same server running 4.0 and the membership provider is the same in the web.config except the connectionstring name of course since they go to different databases

Comment: I have fixed it...a simple restart of IIS got it up and running!